# Extend iso currency data with user currency

Tags: database-design

I have a simple currency table with iso 4217 data:

```
currencies
----------
currency_code char(3) pk
name          nvarchar
```

And I want users to be able to add their own currencies (like cryptocurrencies) in a table like:

```
users_currencies
----------------
user_id int     pk (fk to users table)
code    char(3) pk 
composite primary key (user_id, code)
```

So that they can use to price a product:

```
users_products
--------------
user_id       int pk
product_id    int pk
currency_code char(3) (fk to users_currencies)
price         decimal
```

Then I would copy the currencies table into users_currencies when creating new users.

Is this a good design? What are other possibilities?

I would like to avoid this kind of copy if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be copying data from the `currencies` table into the `user_currencies` table, otherwise that defeats the purpose of having a `currencies` table.

If `users` are creating new `currencies` (besides the ISO currencies) then you could just have a single `currencies` table with the `currency_code` (**primary key**), `name`, and possibly an `isStandard` BIT field that you insert into. Then your `user_currencies` table will just store the mapping of `currencies` each `user` has created.

Then to get all standard codes and the ones a `user` has created you just need to join the two tables together like so:

```
SELECT currencies.[name]
FROM currencies
INNER JOIN users_currencies 
    ON currencies.currency_code = user_currencies.code -- Gets only the user created currency codes
    OR currencies.isStandard = 1 -- Gets all the ISO currency codes
WHERE users_currencies.user_id = 'SomeUserId'
```

You can even create a **View** to save the above query minus the `WHERE` clause, and adding in the `user_id` field to the `SELECT` list, so you can later filter by a specific user.

Comment: I liked this solution, the only problem is that if two users create currencies with same code and different names.

Comment: @MarcosSmith Not possible when the `currency_code` field is the **primary key**, this ensures unique values in that field. Though I assumed it was more of an `id` kind of field based on it being the **PK**. If you do need to also support the case you mentioned, where two currency codes can exist with different names, then you need to add a unique `id` field to the `currencies` table as the **primary key** as well (and use that to reference a particular currency, in both the `user_currencies` table and the example query I provided above, in place of the `currency_code`).